# How do I save scores in my game using cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am currently making an Jeopardy game on the topic of HTML using jQuery. Right now it works well, but I want to add a *recent saved scores* tag using cookies. I don't know how to achieve this.

I know cookies but I don't know how I will get the name and score and then save it.

I want to do something like this:

**Recent Saved Scores**

{NAME HERE}....{Score HERE}
{NAME HERE}....{Score HERE}
{NAME HERE}....{Score HERE}

And it's supposed to save.

Here's a link to my game: http://redirectme.yolasite.com/resources/jeopardy.html

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE! YOUR USE OF ALL CAPS BOLD IS HIGHLY OBNOXIOUS!**

Comment: Uhm ... Let me get this right: You want to display ALL recently saved scores by using a cookie?

Comment: Also, you should `.toLowerCase()` the submitted answer, as I put in `will` but it said **sorry, the correct answer is "Are or Will".** :(

Comment: @Shaz Tt is 'are or will'.

How do I use toLowerCase()?

Comment: @vzwick Yes. Mean they will have a button that will say. Save Score.

Comment: @hobbs OK. Well good to know.

Comment: @Shawn31313 http://jsfiddle.net/jcdqM/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use something like [jstorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) 
It uses [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or cookies if localStorage is not available.

Comment: Well. Great Answeer! This doesn't help me on how I would make it.

Comment: @Shawn31313 Dude, a) there's not a single reason for downvoting this answer, b) RTFM.

Comment: +1 jStorage is awesome! And I agree with @vzwick - there was no need for the down vote... how do you feel when you get down voted, Shawn?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know how to get/set cookie with javascript, just use json to encode the array of recent scores.

NOTE. cookies will register only results for the particular computer. if you need highscore chart, then you need some kind of backend e.g. php for storing and retrieving results.

let me know if you need any further guidance.

Comment: Yes. I know it will only save on that PC. That PHP thing sounds cool but I don't know PHP.

Comment: @Shawn31313 If you knew PHP you could have the people login and it would show the last time they logged in, their last score, etc. Wouldn't that be cool? Someday I'll help you with that. :)